# Next JS 13 response is different when deployed vs when on client

Tags: api, next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next JS 13 and attempting to deploy my frontend/backend using the new app/api onto vercel. Everything is fine locally but when deploying I have an issue with response.

I'm making an "api call" client side through the new server components like this:

```js
const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/posts`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

// the api endpoint looks like this:
export async function GET(request: Request, response: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json(posts, {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("request error", error);
    NextResponse.json({ error: "error getting posts" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I'm debugging this value locally and console.logging response.text() just to see what it gets me, it gives me a json parseable value that looks kinda like this:

```json
[{"id":"cldguokoj0000qp35dzlm2ei6","createdAt":"2023-01-29T03:56:50.228Z","updatedAt":"2023-03-09T06:55:32.783Z","title":"AI is eating humans for knowledge","category":"Tech","content":"<!DOCTYPE ht...
```

which is expected.

however, when attempting to deploy, this same response.text() gives me this instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://assets.vercel.com" rel="preconnect"/><link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com" rel="preconnect"/><l..
```

which is html.

Maybe I am completely missing something but I am unable to find any resource or any information on how to adjust or change this issue. I have checked for hours and the env variables are correct, everything is correct down to just the response is sending a different format when attempting to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the new app folder with new route handlers (GET, POST, ... functions).

Based on that, I think that new GET route handler does not take 'response: NextResponse' as second parameter but 'context: { params }'

See more about new way of using route handler there: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional

Also, It seems that you have to return the second NextResponse you are creating in the catch section.